# Moving from Django 1.6.x to 1.9.x import model errors

Tags: django, django-models, import

I have a few defined apps in my Django project, each with their own sub-directory (created with startapp)

In the views.py of **app1** I have an import to a model from **app2**

```
from app2.models import MyModel
```

This worked in Django 1.6.x. In version 1.9 I get:

```
Could not resolve variable
```

sometimes on MyModel, sometimes on the filter(..) method, or on both.
If I change the import to

```
from app2.models import * #@UnusedWildImport
```

then everything works just fine.

Has anything changed in 1.9.x (or before) that requires a different mode of importing models external to the app?
I think I can rule our circular import problems as this would have failed in 1.6...

**Edit**: Based on the comments I started wondering whether this might be a PyDev problem.
I tried:

1. Removing and re-adding Python to PyDev - it did not help
2. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534599/5958359 - removing the myproject/src folder from PYTHONPATH worked ... with a caveat. 
   **The error did not appear when I *completely* removed the import statement, so this is not a good solution**

Comment: I'm using your exact syntax with v1.9.1, and my table imports without error.

`from tables.models import Zgtdupe`

Comment: include your code and the complete traceback -- cut and paste it

Comment: @joelgoldstick unfortunately the code is too long to include. What I noticed is that the error is **only** in the Eclipse editor ... the code runs just fine ...

I noticed this because Eclipse marks errors in a Python file only when the file is open and I had a particular file that was closed ... but its code ran correctly ... when I opened it I got the errors ... so maybe the problem is Eclipse related ...

Comment: Well, if the code is too long, still copy and paste the complete error message.  It will include traceback and line numbers to pinpoint the issue

Comment: @joelgoldstick the complete error message is "Could not resolve variable" or "Undefined variable from import" depending on whether the error is on the model class or one of the get/filter messages. There is no traceback as the error is compile time in Eclipse. As I mentioned in a previous comment, the code works fine (apparently) when I run it ... I just get an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PyDev error.

Searches haven't yielded an adequate solution - most simply explain how to disable the error - so I will not link to any solution here.
My workaround, as much as I don't like `from xxx import *` seems like the best temporary solution.